# Sql file run by SQLCMD.exe does not work for Entity framework 6 SqlFile() method

Tags: t-sql, transactions, entity-framework-6, sqlcmd

When I run a Entity Framework migration on deploying a asp.net web app I get this error:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near ':'.]
```

My sql scripts **starts** with:

```
:On Error Exit
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
Begin Transaction
set ANSI_WARNINGS  OFF

INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([ID], [Key], [Parent]) VALUES (1, N'bla', NULL)

...
```

When I run this script with SqlCMD it works fine of course, because this script was optimized for SqlCMD.

But it does not work when entity frameworks 6 `SqlFile("scriptfile.sql");` method is executed because the very first ":" seems to be the problem. But I need that ':On Error Exit' directive because of SqlCMD.exe.

My final goal is to have a sql file with many sql inserts wrapped by a transaction which aborts when any error occurs and this should work for SqlCMD and EF 6 SqlFile method.

How can I fix that?

Comment: I don't have much experience with migrations, but why do you mix migration code and SQLCmd code? It seems to me that the insert statements should occur in a Seed method, which can easily be made transactional.

Comment: both approaches deliver the same *.sql file into different systems. Both systems deployments are done with different tools because the infrastructure is heterogen. Anyway I just have a solution. I strip out everything with before/after the insert statements when deployed to azure which is doing the EF migration.